# Getting to prompt with GitBash in Windows 7

Tags: git, windows-7, ssh-keys

I have downloaded and installed Git for windows from [this Google code page](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list) and have followed  [this excellent tutorial](http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/) to install Git on my Windows 7 machine. I have also correctly established my SSH keys and have linked them to my Github account. I can successfully clone repositories using Gitbash which verifies my keys are set up correctly. However, when running Git Bash from the start menu, I get a blinking cursor and can't see the prompt.

Thanks in advance for your help.

P.S. First question ever on stackoverflow :) Sorry for any mistakes.

Comment: Probably not the problem, but just in case: I have a decent computer running windows 7 and it takes a full 20 seconds before I get a prompt (just a blinking cursor until then).

Comment: Thanks. I have waited much longer for the prompt to appear. Will try again though.

Comment: I've installed msysgit and it doesn't behave in the above mentioned way. Did you try opening the batch file under your installed\msysgit\bin\path?

Comment: Something is really wrong if it takes you 20 seconds to launch git bash. On my win7 laptop it's practically instantaneous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just released from the github team is [github for windows](https://github.com/blog/1127-github-for-windows). I think this will get you closer to having a git and windows working together.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid any issue with your current environment, try to uncompress the portable version of mysysgit:

[PortableGit-1.7.10-preview20120409.7z](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/detail?name=PortableGit-1.7.10-preview20120409.7z&can=2&q=)

And launch (or make a shortcut to):

```
<path to git1.7.10>/git-bash.bat
```

Comment: Tried this and still get a blinking cursor after running the batch file.

Comment: @DashAli so GitHub for Windows is better (even if  it does include in its distribution a msysgit package)